# Fetch inside content script fails with chrome-extension://invalid

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Inside my content script, I resolve a URL and execute a `fetch` on it:

```
let url = chrome.runtime.getURL('/hints/heart.html')

console.log("url = " + url)

fetch(url)
    .then(r => r.text())
    .then(injectedContent => {
        // do stuff with injectedContent
    });
```

The URL is resolved correctly. I can see that from printing it to the console. The file there also exists.

However, `fetch` is returning an error saying that it's trying to call the URL `chrome-extension://invalid`.

I already added the path the `web_accessible_resource` in the manifest:

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "/hints/*" ],
      "matches": [ "https://*.myurl.com/*" ]
    }
  ]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing.

Comment: @wOxxOm I always reloaded it via a browser extension and it always worked. Now I've reloaded it via the extensions page as you suggested and the code is working! I don't know why it didn't work through the reloading extension!

Answer (score 2):

Always reload your extension from chrome://extensions/ when you modify files like background.js or the manifest.json.

You can use the normal page refresh when you only modify html files and the js files linked to them (popup.html and popup.js for example).

Comment: Thank you. I was using a Chrome extension that was supposed to reload the script but I guess that doesn't work properly.

Comment: 100% same issue here, I was using the chrome extension and it didn't reload the manifest. Had to remove/reinstall the extension.